# How to align a shape to stick to another in AE?

Tags: shapes, 3d, adobe-after-effects

I'm new to After Effects but I did some work with Photoshop in the past.

I'm trying to create a diamond with AE (and make a gif later so it rotates).
To be super clear - I'm trying to convert the image below into 3D:

[image]

I'm sitting here for 12 hours and trying to perform some basic operations in 3D and I'm totally stuck. For now I have two shapes in my composition, a simple rectangle and a polygon (polygon to make things easier):

[image]

I'm trying to align the triangle to the polygon somehow in a 'smart' way, not by moving the x/y/z position by 1/10 of the pixel each time, rotating the camera and checking if it fits.

Is there any tool in Adobe AE which will help me do this?
I just need to fit the triangle's basis to one of the polygon's edges so it matches perfectly like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Layer snapping feature.

It also works in 3D space.

basically, you need to
-set anchor points of each items on the edges,  that should be magnets
-press ctrl to toggle snapping on
-drag the object to another one

check the video instructions for more info https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/how-to/using-layer-snapping-aftereffects.html